# Getting data from multiple tables and performing a calculation

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sum

Basically I have 3 tables,  a product table that contains the id, type and price, a order table that contains id, customer id and a process table that contains an order_id, aircraft id (both join to make a composite) and quantity.

I want to be able to display the customer id, order id, type and quantity, now each customer can have multiple orders with the same order id.
I want to then be able to calculate the total based on the that customer has ordered.

any ideas what I could use? for example nonequi join, or inner joins, select statements, sum function. as I am not sure which method is easier

thanks :)

Comment: Sounds like `group by` to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use inner join on the three tables , group by customerId and apply sum() function on quantity   . Also whatever columns that  you retrieve in Select clause  should be mentioned in Group by clause or have some aggregate function applied on them.